# vue.js get route name in App.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I used vue-cli with webpack to build up the vue project.
Then I installed vue-meta-info to set up the seo.

I want to set up the Page title with the templates and the route name. 
However , I cannot get the variable in router.

**rotuer/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld,
    },
  ],
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: 'App',
 metaInfo: {
    title: "My Website - "+ route.name,
},
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the router's `beforeEach()` helper.

Example:

### routes.js

```
import Foo from '@/components/Foo'

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Foo',
      component: Foo,
      meta: {
        title: 'Foo'
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

In `app.js` or `main.js` or whatever your main Javascript file is. Placing the code in one of the aforementioned JS file will allow all pages to update the title accordingly and is a much cleaner way to handle the titles.

```
import router from '@/routes'

// your other codes here

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.title = `My website - ${to.meta.title}`
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes title from every component to root component, One way is by `$on .... $emit`,

```js
const Door = { template: '<div>Door</div>',
  mounted: function () {
     vm.$emit('title', this.$route.name);
    } 
  }
const Bedroom = { template: '<div>Bedroom</div>',
  mounted: function () {
      vm.$emit('title', this.$route.name);
    } 
  }
const Kitchen = { template: '<div>Kitchen</div>',
  mounted: function () {
      vm.$emit('title', this.$route.name);
    } 
  }
const Hall = { template: '<div>Hall</div>',
  mounted: function () {
      vm.$emit('title', this.$route.name);
    } 
  }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Door, name:"You are in door"},
    { path: '/bedroom', component: Bedroom, name:"You are in Bedroom"},
    { path: '/kitchen', component: Kitchen, name:"You are in kitchen"},
    { path: '/hall', component: Hall, name:"You are in hall"},
  ]
})

var vm = new Vue({
 router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World',
    title:'no title set'
  },
  mounted: function(){
  this.$on('title', function (title) {
    this.title = title;
  })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>Title : {{title}}</div>
  <router-link to="/">Door</router-link>
  <router-link to="/bedroom"> | Bedroom</router-link>
  <router-link to="/kitchen"> | Kitchen</router-link>
  <router-link to="/hall"> | Hall</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle is](https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/xcfjthbo/4/)

Another way is using `$parent`,

```js
const Door = { template: '<div>Door</div>',
  mounted: function () {
      this.$parent.title = this.$route.name;
    } 
  }
const Bedroom = { template: '<div>Bedroom</div>',
  mounted: function () {
      this.$parent.title = this.$route.name;
    } 
  }
const Kitchen = { template: '<div>Kitchen</div>',
  mounted: function () {
      this.$parent.title = this.$route.name;
    } 
  }
const Hall = { template: '<div>Hall</div>',
  mounted: function () {
      this.$parent.title = this.$route.name;
    } 
  }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Door, name:"You are in door"},
    { path: '/bedroom', component: Bedroom, name:"You are in Bedroom"},
    { path: '/kitchen', component: Kitchen, name:"You are in kitchen"},
    { path: '/hall', component: Hall, name:"You are in hall"},
  ]
})

new Vue({
 router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello World',
    title:'no title set'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>Title : {{title}}</div>
  <router-link to="/">Door</router-link>
  <router-link to="/bedroom"> | Bedroom</router-link>
  <router-link to="/kitchen"> | Kitchen</router-link>
  <router-link to="/hall"> | Hall</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/xcfjthbo/)