# How to get current name of route in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to get the name of the current route of vue-router, i have a component menu with navigation to another componentes, so i want to dispaly the name of the current route.
I have this:

```
created(){
    this.currentRoute;
    //this.nombreRuta = this.$route.name;
},
computed:{
    currentRoute:{
        get(){
            this.nombreRuta = this.$route.name;
        }
    }
}
```

But the label of the name of the route does not change, the label only show the name of the first loaded route.
Thank You

**EDIT:**

[image]

Image to show what i want

Comment: Did you try to manually entering the url of your route in the browser address bar?

Comment: @bgsuello everything works, only i want to show a label in the template of the name of the current route in the title of my navigation menu component

Comment: Your getter should return `this.$route.name`.

Comment: computed may not be the place to do this, try running a method that sets this.$route.name in the mounted() hook

Comment: OR try doing it in the `beforeEach` hook in the routes file, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685780/vue-js-get-route-name-in-app-vue

Comment: @DanOswalt thats a good solution, i will use it, but i already update my question of what i want, is the name of the current route in a label.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You are using `computed` incorrectly. You should return the property in the function. See the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) for more information.

Here is your adapted example:

```
computed: {
    currentRouteName() {
        return this.$route.name;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
<div>{{ currentRouteName }}</div>
```

You can also use it directly in the template without using a computed property, like this:

```
<div>{{ $route.name }}</div>
```

Comment: @ali6p I think, you mean `$router.currentRoute` (with an additional `r` at the end). This command returns the `$route` object. See also https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute and https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I use $router.currentRoute.name but I wrote without **r** :) Thank you. So what do you think? I define router in main.js and use $router.currentRoute.name. Only .name doesn't work.

Comment: If your template does not get updated with the above computed variable, the problem is probably somewhere else. Are you sure, you are actually updating the route? You might want to ask a new question on StackOverflow and link it here.

Comment: this example return always "null" why?

Comment: At this point in time, the right answer is probably `this.$route.path`. Try and `console.log(this.$route)` and see if there is anything else you would prefer.

Comment: Make sure before you use  `this.$route.name` you have defined the `name` properly on each route in your router

Answer (score 56):

**Vue 3 + Vue Router 4**

Update 5/03/2021

If you are using **Vue 3** and **Vue Router 4**, here is two simplest ways to get current name of route in `setup` hook:

**Solution 1**: Use `useRoute`

```js
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
export default {
  setup () {
    const route = useRoute()
    const currentRouteName = computed(() => route.name)
    return { currentRouteName }
  }
}
```

**Solution 2**: Use `useRouter`

```js
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
export default {
  setup () {
    const router = useRouter()
    const currentRouteName = computed(() => router.currentRoute.value.name;)
    return { currentRouteName }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `setup()`, I just used `computed: { route: () => useRoute() }` and then ``{{ route.name }}`` in the template

Answer (score 20):

I use this...

```
this.$router.history.current.path
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Can you explain why it works to solve the OP's issue? Why do you "use this"? Explanations help future users, increase long term value, are of higher quality, and are more likely to be upvoted. Consider editing to add more context.

Comment: This works, but only in Vue 2. Starting with Vue 3, accessing the current route from within `$router` is `.currentRoute.value.path` as described above

Answer (score 10):

In Composition API, this works

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

let currentPathObject = router.currentRoute.value; 
 
console.log("Route Object", currentPathObject)

// Pick the values you need from the object
```

Comment: This is absolute working with VUEJS 3 with Composition API.

Answer (score 3):

I used something like this:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
```

then declared

```
const route = useRoute();
```

Finally if you log `route` object - you will get all properties I used path for my goal.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can **access AND watch current route's name** using `@vue/composition-api` package with **Vue 2 in TypeScript.**

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, watch } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyCoolComponent',
  setup(_, { root }) {
    console.debug('current route name', root.$route.name);

    watch(() => root.$route.name, () => {
      console.debug(`MyCoolComponent- watch root.$route.name changed to ${root.$route.name}`);
    });
  },
});
</script>
```

I will update this answer once Vue 3.0 and Router 4.0 gets released!

Comment: This is a lot of code for something so simple!

Answer (score 2):

I use this...

```
this.$route.name
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Laravel app I created a `router.js` file and I can access the router object in any vue component like `this.$route`

I usually get the route like `this.$route.path`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.$router.currentRoute.value.name;
```

Works just like `this.$route.name`.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Vue 3** and **Vue Router 4** with **Composition API** and computed:

```
<script setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue'
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

    const router = useRouter()

    // computed
    const currentRoute = computed(() => {
        return router.currentRoute.value.name
    })
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{ currentRoute }}</div>
</template>
```

⚠ If you don't set a name in your router like so, no name will be displayed:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/step1', name: 'Step1', component: Step1 },
    { path: '/step2', name: 'Step2', component: Step2 },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get id (name) of current page in composition api (vue3):

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export function useFetchPost() {
  const currentId = useRoute().params.id;
  const postTitle = ref('');

  const fetchPost = async () => {
        try {
        const response = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${currentId}`
    );
        postTitle.value = response.data.title;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } finally {
      }
  };

onMounted(fetchPost);

return {
  postTitle,
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Using composition API,

```
<template>
 <h1>{{Route.name}}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router';

const Route = useRoute();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Vue 3.2** using Composition API

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  
  import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

  const route = useRoute();

  const currentRouteName = computed(() => {
    return route.name;
  });

</script>

<template>
  <div>
   Using computed:{{currentRouteName}} 
   or without using computed: {{route.name}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method on **vue 3** & **vue-router 4**
It works great!

```html
<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    setup() {
        const route = useRoute();
        const routeName = route.path.slice(1); //route.path will return /name

        return {
            routeName
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

```html
<p>This is <span>{{ routeName }}</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I've Tried and it Worked:**

Use Following in Your Elements;

```
{{ this.$route.path.slice(1) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vue 3 + Vue Router 4 + Pinia store (or any other place outside of vue components)**

@KitKit up there gave an example how to get route if you are using **Vue 3** and **Vue Router 4** in `setup` hook. However, what about state management in **Pinia store** ?

**In vue@2 and vue-router@3.5.1**: We could have used `router.currentRoute.query.returnUrl` like so (example in vuex state management):

```js
import router from "@/router";

const state = initialState;
const getters = {};
const actions = { // your actions };
const mutations = {
    loginSuccess(state, user) {
        let returnUrl = "";
        if(router.currentRoute.query.returnUrl != undefined)
            returnUrl = router.currentRoute.query.returnUrl;
    },
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
};

export const authentication = {
    actions: {},
    mutations: {},
};
```

**In vue@3 and vue-router@4**: We have to append `value` to `currentRoute` like so:

```js
import router from '@/router';

export const authenticationStore = defineStore('authUser', {
    state: (): State => ({
        // your state
    }),
    getters: {
        // your getters
    },
    actions: {
        loginSuccess(user: object) {
            let returnUrl = '';
            if (router.currentRoute.value.query.returnUrl != undefined)
                returnUrl = router.currentRoute.value.query.returnUrl;
        },
    },
});
```