# How do i get the active route the correct way?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using the typical Vue Router configuration [as shown in their guide](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html). What i want is to show the name of the shown route, outside of the `router-view`. So i would need to ask the router which route is active.

I've [found in the router API](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-currentroute) that it has a `currentRoute` property, which i was hoping would give me the active route, and i would read its name, and then i'm fine from there.

To test this, i imported the router like so:

```
import router from '@/router.js';
```

Then tried to read the name of the active route:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        test: router.currentRoute.name
    }
}
```

And displaying it with `{{ test }}`.

It seems like it's sort of doing what i wanted it to, but it's super inconsistent and unreliable. I don't get any errors anywhere, and the route name does not show up, and seemingly does not work. But then (sometimes) if i change something in my component's template, like delete an element, or add an element, and Vue hot-reloads my app, the route name appears and continues working. From there, if i refresh, it won't appear again.

What am i doing wrong, and what is the correct way of reading the active route name?

---

#### Subquestion

Would it be a good idea to use `router.beforeEach` for this? Because that seems to work correctly, but it seems like a wrong approach for this...

Comment: did you try this??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126710/how-to-get-current-name-of-route-in-vue

Comment: @kcsujeet thanks for the suggestion, i created a computed property and from it i do: `return router.currentRoute.name;`. The same thing happens, after a hot-reload the route name shows up, after a refresh it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A route object represents the state of the current active route. It
>   contains parsed information of the current URL and the route records
>   matched by the URL.

[Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object).

You can access current route object through `this.$route;`.